# Roslyn CodeAnalysis execution time details

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm currently on a project where build time is quite long. 
The most time consumming task is the CodeAnalysis part. I would like to know which CA rules take too much time to execute, to put them at commit time only, and not at each build. 
Is it a way to know that ? 
(For example, is it possible to get the execution time for each rule in the build "task performance summary" ? )

```
Task Performance Summary:
6>        0 ms  Message                                    6 calls
6>        0 ms  FindAppConfigFile                          1 calls
6>        0 ms  AssignCulture                              1 calls
......
6>    33403 ms  CodeAnalysis                               1 calls
```

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, you *should* be interested in why this takes so doggone long on your machine.  Flaky anti-malware commonly gives Roslyn a hard time, intruding on the named pipe it uses to communicate with the VBCSCompiler.exe process.  So disable it and try again.  And be sure to do it twice in a row so you can eliminate the process startup time overhead as the reason.

Comment: Have you enabled a lot of rules and 3rd party analyzers?